# Cannot allocate unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 2 node cluster and an index with 5 shards and 0 replicas.

```
ES version:1.7.3
```

`_cat/nodes`

Output:

```
ixca-cm-vmops15 10.200.144.76 35 13  d m node.ixca_cm_vmops15 
ixca-cm-vmops16 10.200.144.78 14 22  d * node.ixca_cm_vmops16
```

`_cat/shards`

Output

```
.kibana   0 p STARTED          2   7.2kb 10.200.144.78 node.ixca_cm_vmops16 
p4_search 4 p UNASSIGNED                                                    
p4_search 0 p STARTED    7375235 155.8gb 10.200.144.76 node.ixca_cm_vmops15 
p4_search 3 p UNASSIGNED                                                    
p4_search 1 p STARTED          0    144b 10.200.144.78 node.ixca_cm_vmops16 
p4_search 2 p STARTED    8145526 165.4gb 10.200.144.76 node.ixca_cm_vmops15
```

For some reason,2 of the shards are in an unassigned state. I am trying to allocate a shard to a node with `_cluster/reroute` but its throws a `trying to allocate a primary shard, which is disabled` exception.

`_cluster/reroute` -d

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "p4_search",
        "shard": 4,
        "node": "node.ixca_cm_vmops16"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output

```
{
"error": "RemoteTransportException[[node.ixca_cm_vmops16][inet[/10.200.144.78:9300]][cluster:admin/reroute]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[allocate] trying to allocate a primary shard [p4_search][4], which is disabled]; ",
"status": 400
}
```

However, the reason for the above error is that `"allow_primary"` is not set to `true`. However, I am not willing to set it to false as that will cause data loss for that shard as mentioned in [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/cluster-reroute.html) -

```
It also accepts allow_primary flag to explicitly specify that it is allowed to explicitly allocate a primary shard (might result in data loss).
```

I cannot afford to lose the data that was stored in the unassigned shards(Shard 3&4).

What do I do now? I had, in the past, successfully allocated unassigned shards to nodes manually.So why is it failing now?

Comment: Did you start multiple nodes on the same machine?

Comment: And note that `p4_search 1 p STARTED          0`. That might be an issue as well. 0 documents in a shard of an index that has other shards with way more documents in them.

Comment: "For some reason"... you need to look at the log files of your nodes and see what happened before this issue to have more context before attempting anything related to allocating the "missing" shards. Alternatively, you can actually look on the disk of these nodes and see if there is any data there for those shards.

Comment: Definitely don't use the "allow_primary" flag. It will cause an empty shard to be allocated to the node. Try looking through the logs on those nodes. If the shard data is still on disk, you should see some recovery log messages during initial startup. If there's a reason the shard can't initialize on the node (corrupted files, etc.), it will be in the logs.